# Actualizar campo de dos tablas sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Presento la siguiente inquietud, requiero realizar una actualizacion de la cantidadinicial en la tabla articulo, traidas de la tabla articulo18abril como condicion he establecido que si tienen el mismo id se le asigne la cantidad que corresponde

al tratar de llamar el campo articuloid de la tabla articulo18abril me aparece el error que se muestra en la siguiente imagen y aun no lo comprendo.

algo estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes guiarte del siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

relacionado a tu inquietudes lo que sucede es que no estas haciendo un join para traer la información de la otra tbl, por tanto revisa por favor como te muestro a continuación:

```
  UPDATE a
    SET a.cantidadInicial = art18.cantidadInicial
  FROM articulo AS a
  INNER JOIN articulo18abril art18 
      ON (art18.articuloid= a.articuloid)
  -- WHERE segun sea lo que requieras filtrar en tus condiciones....
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Esta sintaxis no es válida para SQL Server

Comment: Buenas tardes Lamak, muchas gracias por tu apreciación, acabo de ajustar mi respuesta y te referencio un enlace a modo bibliografico al respecto, saludos. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Comment: La sintaxis de ahora es la correcta, pero la condición del `JOIN` no

Comment: oki, si efectivamente el where lo acabo de ajustar para que apunte al articuloid. muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: @JoseReynelChauxPerez gracias, me ha sido de gran utilidad (y)